# I am very new to Arduino and the kit tutorial just told me to wire this, I do not know how to wire it. Can Someone plz help!

Tags: arduino-uno, photoresistor

[image: This is the image]

I can't figure out how to do this the only wires I have are Jumper Wire and M-F 20 Pin DuPont Wire.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124817/discussion-on-question-by-samyam-khadka-i-am-very-new-to-arduino-and-the-kit-tut).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a breadboard, get one. It's a board with lots of holes in it that you can use for experimenting.

Something like this:

[image]
https://www.adafruit.com/product/64?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIz9XDj9bF6wIVcuW1Ch2_kgD3EAQYAiABEgL4DvD_BwE

As Delta_G said in their comment, you could wire a circuit as simple as yours by just putting the wires from the components directly into the terminals on the Arduino, but that quickly becomes impractical. Get a breadboard and learn how to use it.